# Xamarin.Forms with Net.Http

Tags: c#, xamarin, json.net, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

Guys and ladies can you tell me what a problem in this code or in which way I can change Xamarin settings for successful code execution? `Xam.Plugin.Connectivity.CrossConnectivity` says:"Device is connected to the internet", but in any realization `DownloadCountriesListAsync()` stucks (UWP doesnt works, Android with selected INTERNET parameter in manifest too). This code is working in c# console app.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace radacodeTestApp
{
    public class ListsDownloader
    {
        public List<Country> Countries { get; private set; }

        public ListsDownloader()
        {
            Countries = new List<Country>();
            var task = DownloadCountriesListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<bool> DownloadCountriesListAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var vkjsonResponse = await GetResponse(@"https://api.vk.com/api.php?oauth=1&method=database.getCountries&need_all=1&v=5.60");
                var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(vkjsonResponse);
                foreach (var jO in jsonObject["response"]["items"])
                    Countries.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Country>(jO.ToString()));

            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetResponse(string url)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

        }


    }
    public class Country
    {
        public int Cid { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Title;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't, and cannot be, waiting for it to finish.  Don't do that in a constructor.

Comment: I'm not waiting for finish in constructor. Look closer

Comment: Exactly; that's the problem

Comment: Man, this is async  process. It maked for it. Problem is another side. This process stucks at getting http response and with waiting for result program can full freeze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `DownloadCountriesListAsync` method from a background thread; your code is currently calling `DownloadCountriesListAsync` from the Main Thread (also known as the UIThread), which can cause the UIThread to freeze.

I've updated your code below to show how to call the `DownloadCountriesListAsync` method from a background thread.

Async/Await is a tricky beast. Marking a method `async` doesn't mean it will automatically run on a background thread; it just means that the async method has the capability to yield its process to its parent thread until its process is complete. [@Clancey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575000/clancey) did a great presentation on Async/Await at the most recent Xamarin conference. I highly recommend it!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgxJbshvCXQ

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace radacodeTestApp
{
    public class ListsDownloader
    {
        public List<Country> Countries { get; private set; }

        public ListsDownloader()
        {
            Countries = new List<Country>();
            Task.Run(async () => await DownloadCountriesListAsync());
        }

        public async Task<bool> DownloadCountriesListAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var vkjsonResponse = await GetResponse(@"https://api.vk.com/api.php?oauth=1&method=database.getCountries&need_all=1&v=5.60");
                var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(vkjsonResponse);
                foreach (var jO in jsonObject["response"]["items"])
                    Countries.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Country>(jO.ToString()));

            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetResponse(string url)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public int Cid { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Title;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Brandon